# Building a project with Administrative rights on execution?

Tags: windows, tidesdk

for my current project in windows, I have decided to use administrative rights on execution time. I don't want the user to do right click and "run as administrator", but instead that on launch, the app run as administrator without using the trick of the shortcut.

the Exe produced by the building produces an exe file that does not run under administrative rights. There is a way to force TideSDK to build an exe with Administrative Rights on execution?

Thanks.

Clue : I had seen the python code that builds the exe project, but seems there is no flag to build the exe code with adminstrative rights:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\TideSDK Developer\Resources\modules\packaging\js\packaging.js
- C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\tidebuilder.py

Answer (score 0):

A good middleware independent way of doing this is by adding a manifest into the Exe. Ive had success in doing this for PyInstaller, etc

Download: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

then add or modify manifest.

```html
<!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
<!-- level can be "asInvoker", "highestAvailable", or "requireAdministrator" -->
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
   </trustInfo>
```

Comment: I had already tried that, But I want that coming from Phyton, not from resource hacker.